# javascript is not reading my if statement

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function for connection to firebase:

```
firestore.collection('customers').doc(user.uid).collection('subscriptions')
        .where('status', '==', 'trialing' || 'active').get()
        .then(activeSubscriptions => {
          // if this is true, the user has no active subscription.
          if (activeSubscriptions.empty === true) {
            createCheckoutSession(user.uid)
          } else if (activeSubscriptions.size > 1){
            alert("you have more then one active subscription. please manage your subscriptions and cancel one of your subscriptions to access the application")
          } else {
            this.props.history.push(routes.CLIENTS)
          }
        });
```

the `status` of the subscription is actually `active` right now, so I need to do `this.props.history.push(routes.CLIENTS)` <- line, however, it is not and it is calling that `createCheckoutSession(user.uid)` line instead. I assume that my if comparison is incorrect syntax. any ideas?

Comment: The value of `'trialing' || 'active'` is `'trialing'`

Comment: no, in firebase the value of status is actually active, thats why im confused

Comment: The problem is your JavaScript. `.where('status', '==', 'trialing' || 'active')` is equivalent to `.where('status', '==', 'trialing')` because of the way `||` does short-circuiting.

Comment: @Barmar, oh okay. is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try to console activeSubscriptions and print here for better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        .where('status', '==', 'trialing' || 'active').get()
```

is not the way to test if `status` has one of several values. use the `in` test with an array of values.

```
        .where('status', 'in', ['trialing', 'active']).get()
```

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

Comment: right on! This worked like a charm. thank you my friend :)

Comment: @gianluca If this solved your problem, mark it as the accepted answer.